# Finding a,b,c,etc in Quadratic/Cubic Equations

Tags: algorithms

I have been developing an RPG and I finally want to program a better development curve. I have decided to use the following equations

Linear, Quadratic and Cubic

The Linear one is easy. I have no problems with that. But I'm stuck with the other 2.

**Quadratic**

The formula for this equation is $y = ax^2 + bx + c$
What I want to do is find out what $a$ and $b$ are. Given that I know what $y$, $x$ and $c$ are. How would I figure out what this is?

**Cubic**

The formula for this equation is $y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ 
What I want to do is find out what $a, b$ and $c$ are. Given that I know what $y, x$ and $d$ are. How would I figure out what this is?

Can anyone help me with this? This is the first time learning about curves and I am falling flat.

**Bonus Question**
In the Cubic equation, there is a part that looks like the middle of an S. How would I extend that middle in the equation?

**Bonus Question 2**
I'd love to know about more graph based curves built using equations. Do you know of any?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The quadratic is one equation with two unknowns; there are an infinite number of solutions.
The cubic is even worse, there are three unknowns in one equation.

Comment: If you only have one set of value, this will not be enough to find what $a$ and $b$ are. Same goes for the cubic equation. To find $n$ constants of an equation, you will generally need $n$ points therefore $n$ $(x,y)$.

Comment: When you say unknown, do you mean they could be any value and it could match y?

Comment: Well, $a$ and $b$ are unknowns in the quadratic case. Generally you need (at least) 2 equations to solve for 2 unknowns.

Comment: Hmm. I guess this is an impossible feat then for me. Are there any good programs I can use to plot out curves on? The ones I find go up to -50 to 50 on the x/y axis?

Comment: Bonus 1: Yes the middle does look more or less like an S. Do you want to know how the curve of the S is represented in the coefficient of the cubic equation?

Comment: to plot : http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: @ User : It would be great to know!

Comment: Bonus 2 : Have fun on the link I just put, you can check how curves look like, very simple to use.

Comment: @JeremyBeare : Taking the derivative you need the equation $3ax^2 + 2bx + c = 0$ to have two solutions. Do you know how to find this? If the derivative has two solutions, you will observe a change a direction ie an S curve.

Comment: Oh btw I do have another question. That quadratic curve starts increasing slowly and later increases fast. What is the name of the curve that increases fast and later increases slowly?

Comment: I must say, all this curve talk has got me highly interested in hardcore maths again :)

Comment: There are a lot of functions that first increase fast, then slowly; the square root, the logarithm, the arctangent....

Comment: Many indeed. Probably the simplest ones are square root and inverse functions. Another one is 1 - exp(-x). However polynomials all tend to be slow around 0 and increase fast later.

Answer (score 1):

For the quadratic case all you need is two pairs of x and y. Let these be $(x_1, y_1) ,(x_2,y_2)$. On putting these values in your equation we get:
$$ax_1^2+bx_1=y_1-c$$
$$ax_2^2+bx_2=y_2-c$$
$$\implies \left[{\begin{array}{cc}
      x_1^2 & x_1\\
      x_2^2 & x_2\\
\end{array}}\right]
\left[{\begin{array}{c}
      a\\
      b\\
\end{array}}\right]=
\left[{\begin{array}{c}
      y_1-c\\
      y_2-c\\
\end{array}}\right]$$
It is now easy to solve for *a* and *b*.

In case of the cubic equation the only difference is that you need atleast 3 pairs of *x* and *y*. The rest is the same.

The middle part of the S is actually the part between the roots of the derivative of the cubic. To increase that distance you need to increase this distance between the roots.
Consider a cubic $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. Its derivative is $3ax^2+2bx+c$. Let the roots of the quadratic be $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

$$ \alpha + \beta = -\frac{2b}{3a} $$
$$ \alpha\beta = \frac{c}{3a} $$
$$ (\alpha-\beta)^2 = (\alpha+\beta)^2 - 4\alpha\beta $$
$$ (\alpha-\beta)^2 = \frac{4b^2-c^2}{9a^2} $$
To increase the middle portion of the S you need to increase the value of $\frac{4b^2-c^2}{9a^2}$.

**Added after Jeremy's request:**
$$ax_1^2+bx_1=y_1-c$$
$$ax_2^2+bx_2=y_2-c$$

Multiply the equation above by $x_2$ and below by $x_1$
$$ax_1^2x_2+bx_1x_2=(y_1-c)x_2$$
$$ax_2^2x_1+bx_2x_1=(y_2-c)x_1$$
Subtract the two equations
$$a(x_1^2x_2-x_2^2x_1) = (y_1-c)x_2-(y_2-c)x_1$$
$$\implies a = \frac{(y_1-c)x_2-(y_2-c)x_1}{x_1^2x_2-x_2^2x_1}$$
Finding $b$ is now easy.

Learning about matrices will help you in finding the unknown coefficients for curves of even higher degree.

Comment: Well that makes more sense but I am still confused. Could you go through solving a and b a bit more? I haven't seen that sort of bracketing before.

Comment: @JeremyBeare. Those are matrices. Forget the matrices. to get a and b you could just solve the two equations above it.

Comment: Ok I'll do it with a real life scenario. This is for Armour development

Level 1 Armour : (a * (1 * 1)) + (b * 1) = 2 - 1, Level 11 Armour : 
(a * (11 * 11)) + (b * 11) = 64 - 1

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects of your questions:

- How to do it in an abstract, ideal setting.
- How to do it in practice.

First, if you have $n$ unknowns, you need $n$ data points (modulo special cases), like pairs $(x,y)$. Then you get a system of *linear* equations, which you can easily solve.
I would start with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations), but there are libraries which would solve them for you (however, please *do* start with some theory, it would be much easier for you later, as for the software, start with what [BLAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) is).

To give a concrete example, suppose that you would like your model to have the following formula $$y = ax^2+bx+c.$$

There are three unknowns, namely $a,b,c$, so you need three independent data points. Let's make it $(0,1), (2,4), (8,16)$ where the pair means $(x,y)$.
We put this into some engine, e.g. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%3Da%2a0%5E2%2Bb%2a0%2Bc%2C+4%3Da%2a2%5E2%2Bb%2a2%2Bc%2C+16%3Da%2a8%5E2%2Bb%2a8%2Bc) and obtain $a = \frac{1}{16}$, $b = \frac{11}{8}$ and $c = 1$.

Now, how to do it practice is a whole other question. In particular you will often have multiple data points which contain some noise, and you would like to model the general behavior. Some relevant topics are [curve fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) and [regression analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis). Be aware that this area is *huge* and there are whole courses that consider only a small part of it. If you want to dwell more on this, I would recommend machine learning first to gain a wider perspective (e.g. there are some great online resources on this). If you are *serious*, but want to stick to only a few methods, I would recommend processing your data with [Kalman filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) (probably an overkill).

Finally, if this is not a system-critical part, some trail-and-error might give you better results than using some mathematical approach you have no experience with.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Well that makes it easier! Now I have a new problem. I did it with 3 points. The first point was with x being 1 (Where I want the curve up to start). The last 2 points being where I the last values of Y. Now the equation does indeed work for all points, the points between 1 and the last 2 points for the majority bring a negative y. I guessed this was because one of the points need to be in the middle of the curve. But then this causes a problem because I want to use the graph to find the points between the beginning and the end. What do I do?

Comment: @JeremyBeare It's hard to say when I don't know your data. However, maybe the quadratic equation is not the one you are looking for, how would the ideal curve look like?

Comment: I think you are completely right. Everything I have done doesn't work.

http://i114.photobucket.com/albums/n260/danielkin09/Curves.png
http://www.rpg.net/news+reviews/columns/RFF_045.gif
http://www.rpg.net/news+reviews/columns/RFF_044.gif

These are the types of curves I want to achieve. Whenever X increases, Y must always increase

Comment: @JeremyBeare Take a look at [S-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), also at [exponential function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) and [logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm). Maybe something like $y = a\cdot \exp{(b\cdot x+c)}$ or $y = a\cdot \log{(1+b\cdot x)}$ or $y = a\cdot \tanh{(b\cdot x+c)}$ would work better for you.